# VOID: static and non-static called on same button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, void

I have button, onclick="weboscio".

I want to do two things on click:

```
public void web(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, about.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
    //opens a new layout
```

And also:

```
 public static void warning(Context context, int id, int titleResId, int textResId, PendingIntent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String title = context.getString(titleResId);   
    ....etc....
    // to open a pop-up window
```

Just put there two voids into one activity and call it on button click. I searched quite a lot, but nothing useful.. I also tried:

```
public static void weboscio(String args[]) {
        home something = new something();
        something.web();
        new something().warning();
```

It obviously works only for non-static voids.. and also I were getting an error in .web(HERE) and .warning(HERE).

> **weboscio** = onclick function
>
> **home** = main java activity
>
> **web** = activity supposed to open new layout
>
> **warning** = activity supposed to display some warning on new layout

Comment: `home.warning();`

Comment: Heh I overlooked it, but still, why Iam getting errors in new home.warning**(THERE)**; - because warning below has: **(Context context, int id, int titleResId, int tex)** and also, it is public static and non-static in one, and studio doesn't like it  needs to be called with Instance, but hell I know how to do it :(

Comment: You still need to pass parameters to those functions if you are not already...

Comment: I know that, but how do I pass multiple parameters?  I tried it, but I were getting only more errors :(

Comment: If you are still having problems, you can post a stacktrace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after looking at the problem again, I understand what's going on.  You're simply calling the static method incorrectly.

Do this instead:

```
public static void weboscio(String args[]) {
    home something = new something();
    something.web();
    home.warning(...);
```

A static method is called through the class, not the instance of the class.

Here's an example:

```
String x = new String("Hello");
x.concat("World"); // non-static

String y = String.join("Hello", "World"); // static
```

Comment: oh thanks! but shouldn't be there **new home();** instead of **new something();** ?

Comment: No, static methods don't use an instance.  They're used when an instance isn't needed.  Like using "String.valueof(...)", you don't need an instance of a String to use the method.  That's the purpose of static methods.

Comment: I added an example of the difference to my answer.